# Testing my DevelopmentPod from Example Project not working

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, cocoapods, xctest

I'm writing my own Pod and wanted to start unit Testing. But I can't figure out where in my Project to test. 
I thought the Example Project was the right place to write my Tests, but from there I don't have internal Access to my DevelopmentPod.

I have to say it's the first XCode Project in which I want to unit test. So I'm not very familiar with it.

Any help on how unit Testing in Cocoapods should be set up is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried importing you pod to unit tests via `#import <YourPodName/File.h>` or `@import YourPodName;`?

Comment: Yes, I use Swift and I have import YourPodName at the top of my file. It's not that I don't have access to the Pod. It's just I can't test single functions without making them public. Wich is clearly not what I.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the class has to be marked as `open` in order for it to be accessed. On a personal note; I tend to prefer to write my unit tests in the pod project itself, not in the example application.

Comment: @Hodson, Thats seems right to me. How do you configure the Unit Testing in your Pods? I can't get my head around this. Which workspace do you use? What do you configure when adding the test Target? Every tip is very helpful. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It depends on how you setup your project. When I wrote my last Pod, I actually started a new `Single View Application` project in Xcode rather than creating a `Cocoa Touch Framework`. It was then very easy to just add a Test Target (you can even tell Xcode to add it when you create the project). All I do then, is when creating the `PodSpec` is tell it to only include the classes that are relevant to the pod by making use of `s.source_files`. Doing it this way also means your Pod project can also act as your example app meaning you only need to add one project to your CI server if you use CI.

Comment: @Hodson Oh that sounds like a nice way to go. I started my pod using pod lib create, but I find it difficult to figure stuff like this out, due to not really the best documentation on Cocoapods side for starting Developers like me :).